# jQuery + Gravity Forms: Perform jQuery on bad validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I use some jQuery on a current gravity form. However, when I submit the form and it comes back with bad validation, I lose some of the jQuery targets.

I'm curious how I can swap out `$(document).ready(function() {` with something that will call my jQuery once the fields are reloaded with bad validation.

I've tried `$("#gform_submit_button_1").click(function() {` however, that's too soon. It needs to happen when the new fields come back from ajax.

Comment: I have done 2 addon for GF but always using my own javascript files. I know that their fields have an AJAX feature which I never used. Please gives more info...

Comment: Not sure what other info to give, @NomikOS .. For now, I've just disabled ajax.

Comment: I have GF installed, give me an example of your problem to recreate it here. It is sure that we can find a workaround...

Comment: When AJAX is enabled, it rewrites all the HTML on submission even with bad validation. So I target specific elements with jQuery on page ready, and then when it rewrites those with AJAX the jQuery basically becomes useless. I need code to reactivate the jQuery when the new html loads after AJAX.

Comment: Have you tried using a different form of event delegation? Try `on` or `live` depending on your jQuery version, they update as elements are added to the DOM.

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a hook provided for use here: `gform_post_render`

This jQuery hook is fired every time the form is rendered to allow custom jQuery to be executed. This includes initial form load, going to the next/previous page on multi-page forms, form rendered with validation errors, confirmation message displayed, etc.

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){

    // code to trigger on AJAX form render

});
```

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/gravity-forms/extending-gravity-forms/hooks/javascript/gform_post_render/

Answer (score 4):

For some reason Gravity Forms still hasn't added a jQuery hook for failed form validation. What they recommend doing is checking for the existence of `div.validation_error`.

```
jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function(e, form_id) {
    if ( jQuery('div.validation_error').length > 0 ) {
        console.log('Form validation error.');
    }
});
```

You'll notice I'm not specifying a parent when I check for the validation error element: `jQuery('div.validation_error')`. If you have multiple forms on the page this would cause issues. The `form_id` parameter that is returned contains the form's ID in the database (e.g. 1, 2, 35, etc.) but I'm not sure if this value matches the forms ID in the HTML, e.g. `<form id="gform_1">`. If it does match, then it's good practice to specify the parent, so you could do:

```
if ( jQuery('div.validation_error', '#gform_' + form_id).length > 0 ) {
```

Maybe somebody else could weigh in and let us know if the form's HTML ID will always match the form's database ID.

Comment: It looks like Gravity Forms updated the validation error class from `.validation_error` to `.gform_validation_error `. So the example code above should be:

`jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(e, form_id) {
    if ( jQuery('div. gform_validation_error').length > 0 ) {
        console.log('Form validation error.');
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Gravity forms does supply a `gform_confirmation_loaded` hook, but I don't think this will work in your case since it's not loading the confirmation, but the error state form. They don't have a hook for this but I've had success using jquery delegated events. I use the `.gform_wrapper` as my first selector and then target the fields I want to actually target.

See this documentation for more info:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events
- http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/gravity-forms/extending-gravity-forms/hooks/filters/gform_confirmation_loaded/

Answer (score -1):

One solution is: catch the submit event and start a interval that checks your form for changes and then calls your function:

```
$('#your-form').submit(function(){
    html = $('#your-form').html();
    iv = setInterval(function(){
        If($('#your-form').html != html){
            yourfunc();
            clearInterval(iv);
        }
    }, 200);
});

function yourfunc(){
    //your stuff   
}
```

This is however not very neat and it will only work if the html is actually changed after the Ajax call.